# Should the [period] tag be burninated?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, burninate-request

The [period](/questions/tagged/period) tag is currently used to mark questions (currently ~120) about rather different topics:

- The period of a periodic waveform or function.
- A generic period of time in various contexts.
- The period symbol, i.e. dot or full-stop `.`, in different contexts.

Therefore it doesn't seem much helpful and maybe should be burninated.

Comment: Yes, with violence.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella I agree. Period! :-D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first category - periodic waves / functions - is a cohesive topic.  Possibly better to retag those as "periodic" for instance.

The usual practice when a tag is ambiguous I understand is to burninate. That being said, I'm not sure it's not a better idea to just edit the description to make it solely for periodic functions since I don't think the other categories really have cohesion of any kind.

Answer (score 2):

Burn it. It's imprecise for the most appropriate usage. Periodic would be more apropos.